# Must I use arrow functions in this.setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am following [an example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010) in React's documentation on using `this.setState` to toggle an on/off button.

I am experimenting with non-arrow functions in this.setState but have difficulty understanding why non-arrow functions wouldn't work, or if something needs to be added to a non-arrow function to make it work.

This is the official code snippet:

```
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn}));
  }
```

However, the button failed to change from "on" to "off" when rewrote the arrow function as a regular function.

```
    this.setState(
      function(prevState) { 
        isToggleOn : !prevState.isToggleOn;}
    );
  }
```

I've tried adding the `return` keyword before `isToggleOn`, but it didn't work.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the difference of scoping and `this` between an arrow function and a regular function. Am I missing something here?

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) is the source of the React documentation.

Comment: As well as the `return` statement you mentioned, you also omitted the `{` and `}` that mark the start and end of the object literal that were in the arrow function version of the code. That makes `isToggleOn` a (useless) [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) instead of a property name.

Comment: The arrow function is returning an object which is not happening in your `function` example.

Comment: "I'm guessing it has something to do with the difference of scoping and this between an arrow function and a regular function." — Your code doesn't use `this` so, no, that can't be it.

Comment: @Quentin returning the object with `return this.state` didn't work, should I return something else? Sorry I am still a beginner with this.

Comment: Where has `this.state` sprung into the conversation from? The arrow function returns an object created with an object literal: `{ isToggleOn: someValue }`. The function expression lacks a return function and also lacks that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions are purely syntax sugar and can *always* be rewritten using ordinary `function`.

```js
this.setState(
  prevState => ({ isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn})
)
```

`this` doesn't appear inside the function so that's not the issue.

What you wrote -

```js
this.setState(
  function(prevState) { 
    isToggleOn : !prevState.isToggleOn;
// ^__ missing `return`, missing enclosing object {...}
  }
)
```

What you meant to write -

```js
this.setState(
  function(prevState) {
    return {
      isToggleOn : !prevState.isToggleOn
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Another thing I've learned is that `return {` has to be on the same line or else Javascript will interpret it as `return;` due to automatic semicolon insertion. Thank you again.

Comment: you are welcome. another common practice you will see is `return (...)` where you can have newlines appear in `...`. when functions are passed as arguments, i think arrow functions are nice because they make it easier to avoid some of the issues you experienced here. for top-level functions, i usually use `function`.